# Как разбить HTML-страницу на плитки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-дизайн

Мне нужно сделать из HTML-страницы сетку. Чтобы каждая ячейка была заданного размера и чтобы в неё можно было поставить картинку с размером в ячейку. Как это лучше всего можно сделать? Нужна сетка не фиксированного размера, а динамическая чтобы заполняла страницу. А если что-то не помещается то появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки.

Comment: <div style="overflow: auto;"><table>...</table></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, вам вот сюда: http://masonry.desandro.com/

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing
>   elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort
>   of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in
>   use all over the Internet.

Это джаваскрипт-библиотека для расположения контента по сетке. Она располагает элементы оптимально по странице, отталкиваясь от доступной высоты.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, советую воспользоваться Bootstrap. Сетка воздается с помощью div блоков.

Приведенный ниже пример разбивает страницу на 4 вертикальных блока. Которые не имеют ограничений по высоте. А так же при просмотре с мобильного устройства займут позиции друг под другом.

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  <!-- контент блока 1 -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  <!-- контент блока 2 --> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  <!-- контент блока 3 -->    
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  <!-- контент блока  4 -->
  </div>
  </rows>
  </div>
```